# Convert Enum UNDERLYING Integer value toString

Tags: c#, casting, enums

**Trying to get the underlying Integer value for my enum returned as a String.**

Tried

```
return ((int) MyEnumValue).ToString;
```

But fails with

Error   1   Cannot convert method group 'ToString' to non-delegate type 'string'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Comment: Well, *did you intend to invoke the method*? Method invocations always have a () in C#. If you intended to invoke the method then *invoke the method*.

Comment: You are missing the parenthesis at the end of ToString method call. it should be ToString();

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your method return a `string` and not `Func<string>` you need `()` to actually execute the method.

```
return ((int) MyEnumValue).ToString();
```

Comment: hahahahahahahah, well now I feel like a dick.... Sorry ex VB programmer here trying to change his ways...

Answer (score 45):

The less parentheses option is:

```
return MyEnumValue.ToString("d");
```

Comment: When availible, i always go for the least parentheses stackoverflow answer